# How can load a xib from an another class

Tags: ipad

How can load a xib from an another class???

I tried the below code

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[serverlistViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"serverlistViewController" bundle:nil] animated:YES];
```

But it cannot load.

Again I tried the below code

```
    serverlistViewController *ServerlistViewController=[[serverlistViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"serverlistViewController" bundle:nil]; 

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ServerlistViewController animated:YES];
    [ServerlistViewController release];
```

But it also did'nt work.

Can you give me a suggection

Thanks  in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
[self presentModalViewController: ServerlistViewController animated:YES];
```

Try this. May it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
serverlistViewController *ServerlistViewController=[[serverlistViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"serverlistViewController" bundle:nil]; 

[self pushViewController:ServerlistViewController animated:YES];
[ServerlistViewController release];
```

And Select the NIB file, watch out on the file inspector and go to the "Target Membership" section. There you will see your project name with a check box at it's left. Check that box (mark as selected) and build & run your application. [Try This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702725/xib-nib-file-doest-load-properly).