# .XIB / .NIB File doesn't load properly

Tags: xcode, exception, ios4, xcode4.3

My application got SIGABRT throwing error message:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: ... "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the NIB file that is causing the SIGBART error, watch out on the file inspector and go to the "Target Membership" section. There you will see your project name with a check box at it's left. Check that box (mark as selected) and build & run your application. It should work fine.